# Possible to remotely access files on mobile devices using HTML5/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, file, webrtc, sharing

I have a file sharing web app online where I want people to be able to remotely access and upload files from their mobile devices without a client, but clientless via HTML5/JS, to our servers.

I have seem remote support companies log in to client devices just using browser with clients permission.

Thank you for your time
Robert

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file sharing web app online where I want people to be able to remotely access and upload files from their mobile devices without a client, but clientless via HTML5/JS, to our servers.

This isn't possible.

Web applications cannot access files that haven't been explicitly selected by the user. Additionally, they cannot store files on the user's system without a download, and they cannot do anything at all unless they are active in a browser -- they cannot run in the background.

Web applications running on mobile (i.e, Android or iOS) devices are even more limited. They typically cannot interact with most files on the system. For instance, web applications running on iOS can only upload photos from the user's photo library, not arbitrary files.

> I have seem remote support companies log in to client devices just using browser with clients permission.

Either you were mistaken, or something else was going on. For instance, a client application may have been previously installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following exactly what you mean. If you already have the service, that means that you can just create a **form with a filefield** to upload whatever you want, the size limit is only imposed by your web server (apache/nginx/whatever) and your backend service.

You can complicate things a little bit using HTML5 web storage (that's what MEGA uses) but I can't give you any specifics if you don't explain a bit more in depth what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your time Oscar/Dusk. Oscar, when people login to my web app, and they want files on say a laptop or iphone they dont have physical access to, I want them to be able to remotely access those files on those devices through the site (of course after having the devices registered with site and their account )- so in the site it shows say a mini explorer of whats on their phone or laptop and they can choose a file to upload as if they were on the phone or laptop. Now i know there is Syncthing? Maybe have access to synced files between our server and their device? No way w/o a client?

Comment: Oscar did that make sense?